# Aligning problem (image+ text)

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'm working on an image gallery, and I have some problems with aligning of text below the images. Whenever the text fill up more than one line the image gets moved up, which I do not want. Here's a screenshot describing the problem:

[Image of problem](http://zorps.dk/photo_align_problem.png)

I've cut out the images, but you can see the frame so the problem should be clear. Here's my code:

```
<table style="padding:10px; width:500px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
      <div style="width:150px; margin-left:0px;" class="photo_frame">
        <a href="album.php?id=1" title=""><img width="150px" src=
        "images/photos/thumb_6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca.jpg" alt=
        "" /></a>
      </div>

      <p class="photo_total" style="margin-left:2px;"><a class=
      "album_title" href="album.php?id=1">test</a><br />
      22 photos.</p>
    </td>

    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
      <div style="width:150px; margin-left:0px;" class="photo_frame">
        <a href="album.php?id=2" title=""><img width="150px" src=
        "images/photos/thumb_d82c8d1619ad8176d665453cfb2e55f0.jpg" alt=
        "" /></a>
      </div>

      <p class="photo_total" style="margin-left:2px;"><a class=
      "album_title" href="album.php?id=2">Here's an test album</a><br />
      8 photos.</p>
    </td>

    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
      <div style="width:150px; margin-left:0px;" class="photo_frame">
        <a href="album.php?id=3" title=""><img width="150px" src=
        "images/photos/thumb_fc490ca45c00b1249bbe3554a4fdf6fb.jpg" alt=
        "" /></a>
      </div>

      <p class="photo_total" style="margin-left:2px;"><a class=
      "album_title" href="album.php?id=3">AzaraT @ Static
      Underground</a><br />
      3 photos.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

CSS:
.album_title {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
}

.photo_total {
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#969696;
}
```

Any hints? 
Thanks :D

Comment: the images should align, and then there should be added another line under the image. Now the thirds image with three lines of text is aligned higher than the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind setting this css on the tds worked:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: Why are people so weird about tables for layout? Tableless layout was all the rage in 2002 but your modern-day pragmatic web dev shouldn't be throwing hissy fits about one technique vs another. There's pros and cons, that's all I'm sayin'.

Comment: @darkporter - Because it isn't semantic and is widely considered as a bad practise - http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Comment: @darkporter, the modern-day pragmatic web dev ought to know how to style with CSS. If they don't, they don't deserve the job.

Answer (score 0):

For the **1000th** time don't use **f*^(%&*g** tables for non-tabular data, I've said it before and I will say it again I will scalp anyone that does this and then wear it as a trophy.

**For god's sake man it's 2011 use divs and css!**

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Why_I_think_divs_are_better_than_tables

Comment: @AzaraT - Honestly man, you are using one of *the most* documented "no-gos" in the web design world, It takes minimal to no extra effort to do it correctly with DIV's and CSS, and will more often than not make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @JCOC611 - Perhaps, but I have replied to 3 other similar questions, all-be-it in a more mild mannered way, So I thought I'll make an example for when people posting questions see the "similar questions" section they may just see this and see the error of their ways. It just gets annoying after a while :P Its all good though, I'm calm now :D

Comment: I honestly support you, tables suck! Oh, and I'm glad you're calm! :D

Comment: @JCOC611 Good to see I have support, I think I may make a minisite flaming tables to hell, and just post the URL every time people do this kind of stuff...

Comment: What do you think, tablehell.com or htmltablehell.com? Both are available, or something more http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ - esque ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show a code to look at but, from what i see you need to add a line-height property to match your height property.

ex:

```
height:100px
line-height:100px;
```

The other solution is to wrap the text and image tag each with a different div tag instead of both sharing div one, that way you have more control on how you can style each of them.